# How can i throw a picked up object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity and Visual Studio with C#.
I'm trying to throw picked up objects but for some reason everything after if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) doesn't seem to do anything, everything else works just fine.

```
void Update()
{
    distance = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, TheDest.transform.position);
    if(distance >= 1f)
    {
        isHolding = false;
        Debug.Log("Too far from object to pick it up!");
    }

    //check if is holding
    if (isHolding == true)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Destination").transform;
        this.transform.position = TheDest.position;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(TheDest.forward * throwForce);
            isHolding = false;
            Debug.Log("Object was thrown!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general: Do **not** use `Find` and `GetComponent` in `Update`!

They are extremely performance intense!

---

```
// If anyhow possible already reference these via the Inspector
// by drag&drop, then you can completely skip the Find and GetComponent
[SerializeField] private Transform _destination;
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private bool rigidbodyIsKinematic;

private void Start()
{
    if(!_destination) _destination = GameObject.Find("Destination").transform;
    if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, TheDest.transform.position);
    if(distance >= 1f)
    {
        isHolding = false;
        Debug.Log("Too far from object to pick it up!");
    }

    //check if is holding
    if (isHolding)
    {
        // This should actually never happen
        if(!_rigidbody) _rigibody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // The following block shall only be called once
        if(!_rigidbody.isKinematic)
        {
            _rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            _rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;

            // also this should actually never happen
            if(!_destination) _destination = GameObject.Find("Destination").transform;

            // Why are you doing this at all?
            // Note that later you never undo this
            transform.parent = _destination;
        }

        transform.position = TheDest.position;

        // Check if 1 is the correct button index
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            _rigidbody.isKinematic = false;

            // question: should this really be TheDest.forward ?
            // or maybe the direction from this object to Destination which would rather be
            // Destination.position - transform.position
            _rigidbody.AddForce(TheDest.forward * throwForce);
            isHolding = false;
            Debug.Log("Object was thrown!");
        }
    }
}
```

If not even `Object was thrown!` is displayed probably you never reach the `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)` condition. Check if `1` is the correct index.

---

I don't understand why you are parenting the thrown object to the destination .. if there is another `Rigidbody` involved you get in trouble I guess because you shouldn't nest Rigidbodies.

Also note that setting

```
transform.position = TheDest.position;
```

is not good. You should not change transformations through `transform` as soon as there is a `Rigidbody` involved. Rather go through that `Rigidbody` component e.g. using `MovePosition` in `FixedUpdate`. In general you might be interested in rather using a [`FixedJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html) here:

> Fixed Joints restricts an object’s movement to be dependent upon another object. This is somewhat similar to Parenting but is implemented through physics rather than Transform hierarchy. The best scenarios for using them are when you have objects that you want to easily break apart from each other, or connect two object’s movement without parenting.